# How check is path is a app's cache path?

Tags: android

Suppose I have some Stinrg variable that contain some path.

Is it possible in Android to check is this a path is a app's cache path or is a private app's path?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the `String` value against the value returned by

`Context.getCacheDir()`

> getCacheDir()
>   Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem.

Comment: Looks like perfect answer.

Comment: `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`